# Nginx sub/pre/background request

Tags: nginx

Is it possible to do an additional request for each request served by Nginx?

I have a MySQL database in which I store an ID and the number of impressions for each content ID. Each time a dynamic page is generated I increment the impressions value for the corresponding ID. I want to do the same for static content, I therefor would like to call a Perl script to update the database as a sub-request or in background.

I tried using the Embedded Perl Module, this can do the update in MySQL but I am unable to serve the requested page once the update has been done. Is it possible to call this Perl module as a sub request, or are there any alternatives?

In short, this is what I'm trying to do:
request static page: http://mysite.com/document/12345.html 
-> run a script to update the number of impressions for ID 12345
-> return static file 12345.html

Answer (score 0):

http://wiki.nginx.org/HttpCoreModule#post_action will do what you're asking in the opposite order, which will get the response to the client faster.